# can not access my public ip open port?

Tags: networking

I have created a no-ip DNS and it works perfect but somehow i can not connect to the open port on it. I did port forwarding too on my router and the ip address is dynamically updated too.My WAN encapsulation is PPPoA/PPPoE. when i check my open ports online it says port is open. but i can not connect to it by netcat on server i have netcat -l -p 8604

and on client i do nc xyz.no-ip.net 8604 and it returns empty while same thing on lan ip address works plus if i use my public ip instead of DNS still does not work? thanks in advance

Comment: Probably port forwarding not working properly on your router. Try to activate remote administration on ur router and try to access it from outside, to make sure at least you connecting to your device.

Comment: `netcat -l -p 8604` is invalid.. I think you mean `nc -l 8604`?

Comment: @BorisIvanov Telling an end user to enable Remote Administration sounds like a terrible idea. He's probably got a terrible password, and will forget it's enabled, leaving him vulnerable to the Internet until it get's hacked.

Comment: It is diagnostic measure for testing purpose. If you really concern about it please consult router manufacturers make sure they disable it.

Comment: It may be possible that [NAT Loopback](http://opensimulator.org/wiki/NAT_Loopback_Routers) is not supported by your router.